# Rails Newby: Where should plain old Ruby classes reside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where is the best location to put a plain old Ruby class in a Rails application? I'm not sure if it should go in the helper, model, or controller folder or should I create another folder to handle Ruby classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the /lib folder is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The question really is, what purpose does it serve?  Is it data-like stuff?  model for that.  Is it a helper class that adds functionality to other classes or is a utility?  Probably lib.  Etc...

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what your class is trying to accomplish, but in general /lib is a decent enough location.